# Ruby `to_i!` method not working. Wondering why

Tags: ruby, string, methods, integer

I had the following as part of a simple Ruby training program:

*returns an error:*

```
user_num = gets.chomp
user_num.to_i!
```

*works fine:*

```
user_num = Integer(gets.chomp)
```

*works fine:*

```
user_num = gets.chomp.to_i
```

*works fine:*

```
user_numX = gets.chomp
user_num = user_numX.to_i
```

---

Here is the program:

```
print "Integer please: "
#code insert location

if user_num < 0
  puts "You picked a negative integer!"
elsif user_num > 0
  puts "You picked a positive integer!"
else
  puts "You picked zero!"
end
```

Any ideas on why the first instance returns an error but the other three work fine?  The first should work fine.  It's bugging me.  Thanks.

Comment: `user_num.to_i!` does not just "return an error", it raises a specific exception and error message: `NoMethodError: undefined method `to_i!' for "2":String` (if `"2"` had been entered). That tells you precisely what that the problem is: the class `String` does not have an instance method `to_i!`. Pay careful attention to error messages and when mentioning them in SO questions, include all relevant parts of the message, including the line on which the exception was raised.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Ruby Doc, the method String#to_i! doesn't exist, so that should explain why you are receiving what I presume is a NoMethodError.